# how can i generate Javascript and with PHP and put it into a .js file

Tags: javascript, php

I want to generate javascript dinamically with php, but i want the code to appear in a different file, and call it from my index file in order to have a better structured code.

Do you know a good way to do so?

Comment: If it is generated code, why do you want to put it in a separate file ?

Comment: In general, the less dynamically generated JS code you have, the better. Ideally, your JS code should be entirely static, and only the initial data for it would be dynamic.

Comment: "I want to generate javascript dinamically with php, but i want the code to appear in a different file, and call it from my index file."  A really, really bad idea, for many, many different reasons.  Complexity.  Performance/overhead.  Security. Unnecessary processing.  Unnecessary I/O.  Additional risk points/failure points.  Etc. etc.    Don't do it :)

Comment: For instance, i need to generate graphs dinamically, if i use static js i will have a limited number of graphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name a file anything you want as long as the file name ends with `.php` (or whatever extension is run by PHP).

In the past I have used a file name like `script.js.php` so that I know it's JavaScript built by PHP.

At the beginning of the file make sure you change the mime type. **This has to be at the very beginning of the file with no white space before it.**

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); ?>
```

In your index file you would reference it like common JavaScript.

```
<script src="script.js.php"></script>
```

After your header you would have code like this:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's good idea. It's better to put static JS code into file and pass only needed variables from PHP to HTML (not to JS file).

But if you want to do it, you can use, eg. `file_put_contents()` to write to file. Or any other function that can do that (there are many ways).

Also you can consider using `.htaccess` to change, eg. `scripts.php` to `script.js` and generate JS code from it without saving each time to file.